# Clever way to manage and include SAT or any exam's historical questions? (partial include?)

Tags: macros, comments, document-configuration

Suppose, I am writing some handouts for students to prepare SAT (actually, it is some big exam in our country, not SAT). I have several `.tex` files, for example, `polynomial.tex`, `conic sections.tex`, `triangular functions.tex`, each corresponding to a chapter. At the same time, there have been 10 years or more tests of "SAT". And I think I should create several files like below

1. 2018SATquestions.tex
2. 2017SATquestions.tex
3. 2016SATquestions.tex
4. ...

And for example in `2018SATquestions.tex`, I wish the document can be somehow structured like this: (of course it cannot be compiled alone)

```
true or false
\item Can a polynomial be degree $0$?
\item Is $\tan x'=\sec x$?
\item Is $x^2+2y^2=4$ a circle?
...

Fill in blanks
\item How many real roots of $f(x)=x^5+x^3-1$? \rule[..][..]
\item $\sin(120^\circ)=$\rule[..][..]
\item The radius of $x^2+y^2=16$ is \rule[..][..].
...
```

Now, in my `polynomial.tex`, when I wish to include the SAT historical question, I can simply just use commands like `\sat{2018}{torf}{1}` or `\sat{2018TF1}` or `\sat{2018}[tf][1]`, ... whatever. And in `triangular functions.tex`, I can simply just using commands like `\sat{2018}{finb}{2}`, etc.

Then how can I do this? Is there any useful package for such need? Or is there another clever way to maintain the tests? PS: I'm also afriad that the `\input{...}` (or something similar) command will include the whole SAT file, making the compilation speed down, even if I just want to include only one or two questions from some `201xSATquestions.tex`. Can such problem be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not sure if this is a good solution for a great number of questions, but at least it works. The `memory` package allows you to define a structure-like variable and get its contents later. I used the `exam` class which allows for simple questions, see [the documentation](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) for more options. <s>I also took the liberty of creating a `\blank` command with an optional width argument.</s> The `exam` class already has a `\fillin[correct anwser][optional width]` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{memory}

%\newcommand{\blank}[1][1cm]{\rule[-2pt]{#1}{0.4pt}} % Not needed

\begin{filecontents*}{SAT2018questions}
\newdata*{SAT}
\SAT[2018-1]={
\question[6]
True or false
\begin{parts}
    \part Can a polynomial be degree $0$?
    \part Is $\tan x'=\sec x$?
    \part Is $x^2+2y^2=4$ a circle?
\end{parts}
}
\SAT[2018-2]={
\question[15]
Fill in blanks
\begin{parts}
    \part How many real roots of $f(x)=x^5+x^3-1$? \fillin[][15pt]
    \part $\sin(120^\circ)=$ \fillin
    \part The radius of $x^2+y^2=16$ is \fillin[][3cm] 
\end{parts}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\input{SAT2018questions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \SAT[2018-1]
        \SAT[2018-2]
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks great. By the way, does it suppress (avoid) the compilation on the part the user didn't include?

Comment: The parts not included will not be typeset, but I think they will have to be processed. I'm unsure if this takes the same amount of computation. Maybe there is a solution that really suppresses those parts, you should leave the question open I think.